# Associations being removed by update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models which are associated through a has and belongs to many association, call them `Foo` and `Bar`.

Now say I have a `foo` instance and also have `bar1` and `bar2`. `foo` is already associated with `bar1`.

When I try to update the associations and add `bar2` to `foo`, I run in to a problem.

```
foo.update_attributes(bar_ids=>bar2.id)
```

This will first delete the existing association with `bar1` and then add the association with `bar2` so that `foo.bars` will only return `bar2`. I would like the update action to add the second association without deleting the first.

I feel like this is a simple solution but I haven't been able to find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the behavior of the method `bar_ids`, to replace the elements, which is usually what is wanted. If you want to add a new element, you can either add it to the association, like this:

```
foo.bars << bar2
```

or if you need to use the method `bar_ids`, just first get the value and add it to the array, like this:

```
foo.update(bar_ids: foo.bar_ids | [bar2.id])
```

Comment: So after using `foo.bars << bar2` would I then need to call `foo.save`?

Comment: No, it is automatically saved.

Comment: Would this also work if I only had `bar2.id` and not the entire `bar2` object? Or do I need to grab the whole object from its ID first?

Comment: No, it needs the object. If you have just the id, you can `Bar.find(bar2_id)` or use the second suggestion.

Comment: follow up question: Is there a way to remove the association in a way similar to how you created it in the first method? Like `foo.bars.remove(bar2)`?

Comment: Yes, it would be `foo.bars.delete(bar2)`